# Polars `ValueError: could not convert value 'Unknown' as a Literal` when taking mean of function of variable

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

```
┌───────┬─────┐
│ group ┆ var │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ i64   ┆ str │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ 1     ┆ x   │
│ 1     ┆ x   │
│ 2     ┆ x   │
│ 2     ┆ y   │
│ 3     ┆ y   │
│ 3     ┆ y   │
└───────┴─────┘
```

Suppose the above dataframe is called `df` and I want to get the percentage of variables named `'x'` by group. The following gives me `ValueError: could not convert value 'Unknown' as a Literal`. Can someone explain why?

```
df.group_by('group').agg(
    pl.mean((pl.col('var') == 'x').cast(pl.Int8))
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation, [`pl.mean()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.mean.html) is just a syntactic sugar for `pl.col(columns).mean()`. Your code doesn't work because `pl.mean()` expects `*columns: str` (column names) as input, not `Expr`.

But you can use `pl.col(columns).mean()` instead:

```
df = df.group_by('group', maintain_order=True).agg(
    (pl.col('var') == 'x').mean()
)
```

so you get

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬─────┐
│ group ┆ var │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ i64   ┆ f64 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ 1     ┆ 1.0 │
│ 2     ┆ 0.5 │
│ 3     ┆ 0.0 │
└───────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Ah makes sense, thanks. The error message threw me off